# Data type mix up in c

Tags: c, abstract-data-type

Is array a data type in c ? 
If yes can we create variables of array type as in structures, enum .

```
 int arr[10] ;//is this arr is a data type of 10 ints
```

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are a `derived type`, if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.2.5` *Types* paragraph *20* says(emphasis mine):

> Any number of **derived types** can be constructed from the object, function, and
>   incomplete types, as follows:
>
> > — **An array type** describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
> >     particular member object type, called the element type.36) Array types are
> >     characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array. An
> >     array type is said to be derived from its element type, and if its element type is T, the
> >     array type is sometimes called ‘‘array of T’’. The construction of an array type from
> >     an element type is called ‘‘array type derivation’’.

You can create arrays of structures and enums, the only exception is noted in footnote *36*:

> Since object types do not include incomplete types, an array of incomplete type cannot be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is array a data type in C?

"Array" with no further specification is not a separate data type, but once you specify its size and its element type, it becomes a data type. In other words, you cannot define a type that takes "an array of anything" or "an array of a specific type without a specific size", but you can define a data type that is an array of `N` items of type `T`.

> If yes can we create variables of array type as in `struct`s, `enum`?

```
int arr[10] ;//is this arr is a data type of 10 ints
```

Yes, it is. You can tell by examining `sizeof(arr)`: it will be ten times the `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: "Array" is not a data type; "Array of int" and "size 10 array of ints" are data types.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, an array of a data type is another data type.

You could do something like:

```
typedef int intarr3_t[3];

intarr3_t intarr = {1, 2, 3};
```

Answer (score 0):

yes is it an data type and yes you can make a number of them.

To make it clearer, you can make a typedef of an array.

```
typedef char MyType_t [10];
```

Will make MyType_t an array of 10 chars:

```
MyType arrayOfTenChars;
```

Comment: in MyType_t ,is underscore t is essential .

Comment: No, in fact it should be reserved only for library types, it's just the way I've been doing it for 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of an array relates to a *derived* type. Then there are *data* types such as `array of int` and `array of 10 ints`.